# Linux UDev Rule HDMI

Tags: linux, udev

I am currently trying to get a udev rule triggering when a HDMI is plugged into the system running.

from `udevadm monitor --property` I get this:

```
KERNEL[101.131192] change   /devices/soc0/soc/20e0000.hdmi_video (platform)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/soc/20e0000.hdmi_video
DRIVER=mxc_hdmi
EVENT=plugin
MODALIAS=of:Nhdmi_videoT<NULL>Cfsl,imx6q-hdmi-video
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=fsl,imx6q-hdmi-video
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/hdmi_video@020e0000
OF_NAME=hdmi_video
SEQNUM=1870
SUBSYSTEM=platform

UDEV  [101.139132] change   /devices/soc0/soc/20e0000.hdmi_video (platform)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/soc/20e0000.hdmi_video
DRIVER=mxc_hdmi
EVENT=plugin
MODALIAS=of:Nhdmi_videoT<NULL>Cfsl,imx6q-hdmi-video
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=fsl,imx6q-hdmi-video
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/hdmi_video@020e0000
OF_NAME=hdmi_video
SEQNUM=1870
SUBSYSTEM=platform
USEC_INITIALIZED=101138599
```

The rule I built is this:

```
KERNEL=="video*", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="change", EVENT=="plugin", RUN+="export HDMI_CONNECTED=1"
```

But that does not work. Why?

Comment: I am a bit rusty with udevadm but probably exporting a variable is not a good idea, try to touch a file to check if it works

Comment: will do and report,  thanks

Comment: so using RUN+="touch somefile" the timestamp does not change, therefore I assume the rule does not run

Comment: When you edit then do you reload the rules? (something like `udevadm control --reload-rules`)

Comment: yes I reloaded it. even this does not work:
SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="change",  RUN+="touch file"

Comment: Are you literally running `touch file` or are you using an absolute path?

Comment: an absolute path